# Iterating through each row of a single column in a Python geopandas (or pandas) DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, geopandas

I am trying to iterate through this very large DataFrame that I have in python. The thing is, I only want to pull out data from one specific column that contains the names of a bunch of counties.

I have tried to use iteritems(), itertupel(), and iterrows() to no avail. 
Any suggestions on how to do this?

My end goal is to have a nested dictionary with each internal dictionary's key being a name from the DataFrame column.

Also tried to use this method below to select a single column but that will only print the name of the column, not its contents.

```
for county in map_datafile[['NAME']]:
     print(county)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you delete one pair of square brackets, you get a Series that is iterable:

```py
for county in map_datafile['NAME']:
    print(county)
```

See the difference:

```py
print(type(map_datafile[['NAME']]))
# pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

print(type(map_datafile['NAME']))
# pandas.core.series.Series
```